# Why might alarms not work for 30-40% of my Android users?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm currently trying to run a study that prompts participants to report information six times a day for five days using their Android device. To achieve this, I schedule 30 alarms the first time the app is opened. My code works perfectly on my device (Nexus 6p running Android 8.1) and appears to work perfectly for about 60 to 70% of my participants. However, for the other 30-40%, these participants never receive an alarm (most typical) or the alarms stop appearing a day or two into the study.

First, if needed, I create a channel for my alerts

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "my_channel_01";
        String description = "my_channel_01";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Next, I append all 30 dates I want my alarms to go off to the alarmDates list, then loop through the list and set an alarm for each date.

```
public void startAlert(){

    for (int i = 0; i < alarmDates.size(); i++){

        int request_code = 234324243;

        request_code += i;

        String string = alarmDates.get(i);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = format.parse(string);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), request_code, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

My Broadcast receiver looks like this:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Create the notification to be shown



    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "my_channel_01")
                    //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentTitle("How are things going?")
                    .setContentText("Tap here to tell us how you're feeling")
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(2);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    Random rand = new Random();

    int n = rand.nextInt(5000) + 1;

    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = n;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Make sure any previously launched alarms are removed
    mNotifyMgr.cancelAll();
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

I am currently working with three participants to sort out this problem. They are using a Samsung Galaxy J7, LG Tribute Dynasty, and a Galaxy s9+. None of them report seeing any notifications from my app.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are they all using Android 9 Pie? If so, it is possible that their algorithm has deemed your app as taking too much battery, which is possible if you are firing a lot of alarms and notifications. Take a look here on what exactly I am talking about: https://www.androidcentral.com/android-p-features-youll-love-restricted-apps-save-you-battery-life. And also take a look here to see what buckets are and how you can check if your application is indeed being placed into these buckets: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power#buckets

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'll look into it. So far, all users reporting issues appear to be using a version of Android 6, 7, or 8. No reports from anyone using Android 9.

Comment: Nevermind then, sorry. The buckets only apply to the newest version of Android - Android 9 Pie.